# Swagger json object as property

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, swagger

Is it possible to use JsonObject as property in swagger? For example:

```
@ApiModel()
class RequestBody(
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "John Doe")
    val name: String? = null,
    @ApiModelProperty(example = "Coolstreet 1")
    val address: String? = null,
    @ApiModelPropery(example = """
        {
            "name" : "HDD",
            "capacityInGb" : 512,
            "sizeInInch" : 2.5
        }
        """)
    val jsonEntity: JsonObject? = null
)
```

When I try to do like this, I get error:

```
JSON parse error: Instantiation of [map type; class com.beust.klaxon.JsonObject, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.Object]] value failed for JSON property map due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter map which is a non-nullable type; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.MissingKotlinParameterException: Instantiation of [map type; class com.beust.klaxon.JsonObject, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.Object]] value failed for JSON property map due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter map which is a non-nullable type
```

Comment: unless I'm mistaken, swagger uses jackson (a kotlin json library), and with jackson, you'd use `org.bson.Document` to handle json objects, not JsonObject. Might be worth a shot, beacuse it looks like your implementation doesn't know how to transform a `Map<String, Any>` into a `JsonObject` (which is its String representation).